# selenium python generate data uri of an image with headless Chrome

Tags: python, image, selenium, data-uri

With chrome, if I open a website, I can inspect the Sources and find the target image and then copy it as data URI. 
like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...`

Now I want to do that with selenium headless browser, how can I get the data URI of an image if I can locate it through XPath selector?

(the URL in "src" attribute is inaccessible, don't have privilege)

Thanks!

Comment: You may need to rephrase that term: when you have a data-url, you don't need to "download" anything, as the data is already in that url, base64 encoded